# Is it possible to absorb Stripe Connect ACH fees as a platform?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Hi I have implemented Stripe Connect using custom accounts and I am wondering if it is possible to absorb the fees incurred when a connected account sends money via ACH. I notice that Stripe automatically takes the 0.8% fee initially when an ACH transaction is first sent. Is it possible to offset this some how? I thought about creating a user charge for my platform for the missing 0.8% fee when the first send the ACH payment, but that does not seem very reasonable.

I'm also wondering if it is possible to credit money (send money from platform to connected account) since I read that debiting money (taking money from connected account into platform)

My app needs a payflow like this.

1) Connected account sends ACH payment to platform and is credited with in-app money (here is where the issue occurs since stripe collects the fee from the connected accounts payment, the user if depositing to the platform $10, will then only receive $9.20 in-app credit, since if he chooses to withdrawal the money he will only have $9.20 in his stripe connect balance)

2) Connect account can spend his credited in-app money as they please. Or withdrawal the exact same amount again.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. Theres two ways to do this. Stripe Api has a class called Transfer. Or second way you can do Seperate Charges and Transfers and make transfers from platform to connected accounts.